# Magento2.3: How to set the border bottom for whole header?

Tags: magento2.3, template, header, phtm

I have a megamenu in header and want to set the border bottom for the whole header and it should be aligned with the megamenu border but its not working as expected.

I have tried that into the following path:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

My requirement is to put the grey border to whole header and the border should be the same alignment with the border given in megamenu.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can enable template hints, and check it out by yourself. This is how you can know any `phtml` and `blocks`. Make sure your website is in developer mode to do this.

**Go to Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug**

Change value to `Yes` of `Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront`

Comment: I'm aware about that. The issue I'm facing now is something related to CSS. We have a megamenu in header. When we hover over the megamenu the border bottom will be displayed with color. Our requirement is to put the grey border to whole header and the border should be the same alignment with the border given in megamenu.

Comment: you can directly write css in browser and check iif its works. Then simply add it in `style.less` in your custom theme or simply `over ride` template hint `phtml` and write some quick inline css. Either way it would work

Comment: I can set the border but if I try to align with the megamenu border, its not working

Answer (score 0):

Direct editing in the template file is not a good idea.

Please update your current theme CSS file and add the below code in your CSS file.

```
.page-header { border: 1px solid #000000;}
```

You can add color code accordingly.

Comment: I have tried that. But the border should be same align as the mega menu in header. However, if I try with margin-top, the whole header is moving top

Comment: Share the website URL So I can check the CSS

Comment: Share the screenshot so I can give you the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try with template hints as Ali said to know from which template it is loading. Or You can directly apply CSS based on the classes as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question. Please look at it.

Comment: Can you provide any screenshot